# Google cloud european regions mismatch for bigquery and dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations) for bigquery datasets states that the following european regions are available (A):

- europe-north1
- europe-west3
- europe-west2
- europe-west6

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints) for dataflow states these are the available european regions (B):

- europe-west1
- europe-west4

As you can see, there is no overlap between these regions.

We are building an application that

- Creates datasets, bigquery tables etc etc from a php backend.
- Offloads moving the data from various sources to bigquery to dataflow using python scripts

We were stupid enough (in hindsight) to divide our project in those 2 parts, which were done independently. Both work. It never occurred to anyone that this would become our problem (should be obvious by now):

- The php api can't work with B
- The dataflow scripts can't work with A
- Dataflow can't read and write between regions
- We can't host our data outside of the EU for compliance reasons.

**How do we resolve our catch 22?**

Comment: You can deploy Dataflow in any region/zone. Have you tried overriding the region with `--zone`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the `Regional Endpoint` with the actual region/zone that the worker VMs are spun up in for the Dataflow pipeline and which actually process the data.

The `Regional Endpoint` handles the metadata and orchestrates your Dataflow pipeline. If you specify `--zone`, then that's the zone in which the actual worker VMs for Dataflow will spin up in.

Comment: Yes, the confusion was that the _zones_ (which have a suffix like -a or -b) are [listed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) within their regional endpoints, I somehow figured that those where the only zones available to that region, but the trick is to define a zone from a different regional endpoint. I'll edit your answer with a concrete example and accept it, if that's ok with you.